# How to design this many-to-many database?

Tags: mysql, database, jpa, database-design

I want such a database design. It serves to store a list of words in one language, i.e. English, and their translations in another language, i.e. Spanish. So initially I have a table English (id,word,isTranslated).

```
1 i     false
2 love  false
3 you   false
4 hate  false
5 him   false
...
```

"isTranslated" is a boolean indicating whether this word has a translation or not yet.

In the Web front end, each time a number of words are displayed in an html page from the table English. For example:

```
2 love
3 you
4 hate
```

A user then clicks each of these words and submits the translated words in a web form and they are stored into the Spanish table. Unlike the English table, the Spanish table starts with zero records. It gets populated gradually through the html form.

I am thinking the Spanish table should have the same structure as the English does;

Spanish (id,word,isTranslated)

So that I can have another associative table EnglishSpanish(English_ID, Spanish_ID), which stores the translated pairs in two tables. It's a many-to-many relationship. The purpose of this table is to facilitate retrieval of the counterparts of a word in a language.

Does this make sense? The trouble I am having is, how to populate the other two tables Spanish and EnglishSpanish gradually, as users submit their translations over time? The first table English is pre-loaded.

Thank you for your insights and help.

Comment: How would you cope with words that have multiple meanings? e.g. mean can be nasty (you are mean), denote (what does that mean), average and so on. Otherwise it would just be a case of creating the row using the two id's when it's encountered (everytime a translation is added but ensuring that the two fields combined are unique, could have the key as unique or only add if the combination doesn't exist).

Comment: As for multiple meanings, that's why it's a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Ok say mean has 3 associations. User enters mean which of the three (asumming only 1 way duplicates), which of the 3 would you associate the use of the word mean to in the following cases and as/more importantly how programatically? 1) That is the mean of their ages. 2) They were mean to him. 3) What do you mean? Assuming that such translation would be required without human intervention.

Comment: In addition to words with multiple meanings, there are homographs, different words with a common spelling.  I think that mean is really two or three words.  If so, the written word is not a candidate key for the table.

Comment: Shouldn't you show even the translated words?  There may be yet another translation to add to the list.

Comment: Is the translation "symmetric"?  That is, if `I` translates to `ichi`, does `ichi` necessarily translate to `I`?  Note that that implies 2 rows in the mapping table, unless you sort the ids to avoid this "duplication".

Comment: Consider a grander design -- there are "concepts" for which there are "words" in the various languages.  This would help disambiguate words with multiple meanings.

Comment: In English the word "set" has about 40 meanings ("concepts"?), hence will have upwards of 40 translations into each other language.

Comment: In French "ne pas" is two words usually translated into English "not".  But those two word are rarely adjacent in French.  German will really get you into multi-word translations:  Bahnhofstrasse = train station street.

Answer (score 0):

I once designed a dictionary (one-to-one) relationship, as in real world, you will pick up only one best translation for each English phrase:

```
id, term, lang, english_id
1   I     En    1
2   Love  En    2
3   You   En    3
4   我    Cn    1
5   爱    Cn    2
6   你    Cn    3
7   ichi  De    1
...
```

Above Designed also works for one-many relationship

If you want it as many-many relationship, you need 2 tables:

```
id, term, lang
1   xyz   en
2   ...

id1, id2
1    2
1    3
2    5
...
```

Comment: Why not store words in different languages into different tables, rather than create a huge table to store all words?